# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) YII

Tags: yii

**receiving error after entering the DB configuration for installation**

Error 500
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

**Db config file (default)**

```
(
return array (
  'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sarish',
  'emulatePrepare' => true,
  'username' => 'sarish',
  'password' => 's@r15h',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
);
```

kindly help me

this is the install controller code

```
<?php
```

/**
* Rights installation controller class file.

*/
class InstallController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @property RAuthorizer
    */
    private $_authorizer;
    /**
    * @property RInstaller
    */
    private $_installer;

```
/**
* Initializes the controller.
*/
public function init()
{
    if( $this->module->install!==true )
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);

    $this->_authorizer = $this->module->getAuthorizer();
    $this->_installer = $this->module->getInstaller();
    $this->layout = $this->module->layout;
    $this->defaultAction = 'run';

    // Register the scripts.
    $this->module->registerScripts();
}

/**
* @return array action filters
*/
public function filters()
{
    // Use access control when installed.
    return $this->_installer->installed===true ? array('accessControl') : array();
}

/**
* Specifies the access control rules.
* This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
* @return array access control rules
*/
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // Allow superusers to access Rights
            'actions'=>array(
                'confirm',
                'run',
                'error',
                'ready',
            ),
            'users'=>$this->_authorizer->getSuperusers(),
        ),
        array('deny', // Deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

/**
* Displays the confirm overwrite page.
*/
public function actionConfirm()
{
    $this->render('confirm');
}

/**
* Installs the module.
* @throws CHttpException if the user is not logged in.
*/
public function actionRun()
{
    // Make sure the user is not a guest.
    if( Yii::app()->user->isGuest===false )
    {
        // Make sure that the module is not already installed.
        if( isset($_GET['confirm'])===true || $this->_installer->installed===false )
        {
            // Run the installer and check for an error.
            if( $this->_installer->run()===RInstaller::ERROR_NONE )
            {
                // Mark the user to have superuser privileges.
                Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser = true;
                $this->redirect(array('install/ready'));
            }

            // Redirect to the error page.
            $this->redirect(array('install/error'));
        }
        // Module is already installed.
        else
        {
            $this->redirect(array('install/confirm'));
        }
    }
    // User is guest, deny access.
    else
    {
        $this->accessDenied(Rights::t('install', 'You must be logged in to install Rights.'));
    }
}

/**
* Displays the install ready page.
*/
public function actionReady()
{
    $this->render('ready');
}

/**
* Displays the install ready page.
*/
public function actionError()
{
    $this->render('error');
}
```

}

Comment: your database connection is wrong , so  this throws error. This is very basic thing , please go google before ask such simple questions.

Comment: And you shouldn't be giving out you password!

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
 'db'=>array(
                    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sarish',
                    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
                    'emulatePrepare' => true,
                    'username' => 'sarish',
                    'password' => 's@r15h',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                    'tablePrefix' => '',
            ),
```

Comment: check protected/config/ inside main.php file to configure db

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `localhost` to your IP address `127.0.0.1` and add the the port number, and see what happens.

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=sarish',
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too,that's my solution here, i guess your double config DB connection,  mysql error:using password:NO  means your password is empty....  so take a look at /Common/config/main-local.php   , there is a pre-config for db connection,so you no need to config db connection at any other config file.....my english is bad,but i hode you can understand me...